# How to call multiple elements by class and .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am having problems calling multiple elements with the same class name when  using .innerhtml. For instance the url I am working with is:

https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hen

and when I enter the following code in chrome console I get:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('a-size-small a-color-secondary')

<span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">by </span>
<span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">Adore Plush Company</span>
<span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">Get it by <span class="a-color-success a-text-bold">Tuesday, Jun 21</span></span>
...
...
```

But when I enter: document.getElementsByClassName('a-size-small a-color-secondary').innerHTML

I get "undefined". The goal is to get just the text between the span tags.

Can someone give me some guidance? I have tried with different variations including var and even Selection method. It worked with Selection for the first class element but didn't work at all with SelectionAll. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName('a') will give the Object with class name .

for example class name is a and there are many spans with a , then you need get the span value by using index of that object

```
 var x =document.getElementsByClassName('a');

 console.log("value of spans"+x[0].innerHTML);
```

COdepen-http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: console.log(x[0].innerHTML); 

seemed to work only for the first element but went to undefined after

Comment: Mike, for example , i have used x[0] but for all values , you may have loop that object ,for example as below
for(i=0; i< x.length ; i++){
  
  console.log("value of span"+(i+1)+"is "+x[i].innerHTML);
   
}

Comment: updated my codepen ,hope this works for you

Comment: That seemed to work! Thanks!

Comment: cool...if my answer helped your question, can you mark this as answered and vote if possible :)

Comment: too new to upvote unfortunately

Comment: no problem Mike .. :)